# Why Entity framework work locally but not on azure

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-4.1

I have a WCF project which works perfectly locally using the AZURE SQL CONNECTION. But when I deploy WCF project on Azure it will start giving this error.

Testing WCF with no deploy
[image]

Testing WCF deployed
[image]

This was a post which I post recently but not success yet with the answers, but describe a little bit of detail my scenario. I'm getting desperate, I've spend all day long trying to solve it

[Why does throws me a FaultException in WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540827/why-does-throws-me-a-faultexception-in-wcf-service)

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't read a thing in this picture.

Comment: Which thing do you need that can I provide

Comment: @AndersonSilva zooming in browser will make the text in screenshots readable

Comment: Is EF properly deployed to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

> Once you are using model-first / database-first (EDMX) you must use
>   Entity connection string with referencing .ssdl, .msl and .csdl
>   metadata files. Also be aware that you must create your database in
>   design time when creating model from EDMX = you must generate SQL
>   script and execute it to create the database.

For more information check [**Answered by Ladislav Mrnka**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940616/model-first-with-dbcontext-fails-to-initialize-new-database) and [**Code First vs. Database First**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618342/code-first-vs-database-first)

I hope this will help to you.